# How do I normalize Cross-browser Flexbox Bugs in Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having flexbox compatibility problems in Firefox and Safari.

My flex column boxes are 33% each and should go horizontally across the screen. They do that in IE and Chrome. In Firefox and Safari, the information is display in one column vertically down the page.

What do I need to add to my CSS to get it to render correctly in Firefox and Safari?

Here's my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/uy1wn9tu/4/

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="container-3col">
    <div class="box-3col-1">
        <a href="http://www.apple.com"><img class="subcompact" height="116" src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/promo_thumb_sizing_up_116x116.png" width="116" /></a>
        <p><strong><a href="http://www.apple.com">Sizing up the $1.5 Trillion State & Local Contracting Market</a></strong></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.apple.com"><img src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/button_learn_more_116x30.png" width="116" height="30" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3col-2">
        <a href="http://www.ibm.com"><img class="subcompact" height="116" src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/promo_thumb_5_myths_about_competing_in_sled_116x116.png" width="116" /></a>
        <p><strong><a href="http://www.ibm.com">5 Myths About Competing in the State, Local and Education Government Market</a></strong></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.ibm.com"><img src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/button_learn_more_116x30.png" width="116" height="30" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3col-3">
        <a href="http://www.microsoft.com"><img class="subcompact" height="116" src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/promo_thumb_5_things_vendors_sled_116x116.png" width="116" /></a>
        <p><strong><a href="http://www.microsoft.com">5 Things Vendors Who Are Entering the SLED Market Need to Know</a></strong></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.microsoft.com"><img src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/button_learn_more_116x30.png" width="116" height="30" /></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
/* 3 Column Div */

.container-3col {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container-3col > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-3col-1 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.box-3col-2 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.box-3col-3 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.subcompact { margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox 42 or 43. Had your coworker visited the page previously? If so, it might have been a caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce.
On Firefox 42 (Windows 7 x64) the boxes display in a row for me.

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) flex-boxes should work appropriately in all current and major browsers.

I can't find any errors in your CSS either. What browser versions did you test it with? Have you any addons installed that might affect page content and/or style?

Comment: My co-worker was on Firefox 42 and it wasn't displaying in a row